# Empty MVC4 application, how to create a simple test web api controller that returns json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC4 application, and I created a test webapi based controller that looks like:

```
public class User1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public User1(int id, string name)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Test1Controller : ApiController
    {
        public User1 Get(int id)
        {
            return new User1(id, "hello");
        }
    }
```

I noticed that I have a webapiconfig class:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I'm assuming this will by default output json result correct?

When I go to:

```
http://localhost:61146/api/test1/get/1
```

or

```
http://localhost:61146/test1/get/1
```

I get this error:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

How exactly is this mapped, or do I have to drop it in a special folder?  My guess that it would map it by itself since I am inheriting from ApiController

Comment: or does web api only respond with a json GET request?  I want it to spit out the json in the browser

Comment: Looks like your route is missing the `/{action}/` parameter, no? *EDIT* Guess not--a default project create that route. API calls must work differently (and I haven't had too much experience)

Comment: @BradChristie where should that be, sorry don't follow you. (edit) oh action, let me try yes it looks like it is missing, strange! (edit 2) yes that was the problem thanks!

Comment: That may work though i still feel like that's a work-around. Something tells me the methods off the `ApiController` aren't referenced in that way--but more referenced depending on the method (e.g. GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) but I'm guessing. but I suppose if it works, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Web API, the name Post, Get, Put, Delete are (by default) mapped as request method name, not action name. Your API route being:

```
api/{controller}/{id}
```

And the request:

```
api/test1/get/1
```

No suitable match will be found because the framework will try to match 4 tokens to the only existing route definitions, that contains 3 tokens (the literal `api` and two tokens: `controller` and `id`).

If you try:

```
 api/test1/get
```

The framework will find the `Test1Controller` correctly, but, based the route configuration, will bind the token `"get"` to the `id` parameter. When the framework try to find a suitable method based on your request (a GET request), it will find the `Get(int id)` and find a match but will not be able to convert the token `"get"` to an integer, which marks the method as not a good candidate for the request.

However, if you try this request:

```
api/test1/1
```

It will convert the token `"1"` to the int `1`  and the method `Get(int id)` will be a match.

The routing can be confusing sometimes in Asp.NET Web API. I've found that explicitely mapping my route gives me a better understanding of the request. I suggest [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) which will be [integrated in the next version of the Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).